# Coloring numbers from $1$ to $1000$

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

I mostly just need someone to explain to me this problem:

Prove that it is possible to $2$-color the integers from $1$ to $1000$
so that no monochromatic arithmetic progression of length $17$ is formed.

For some reason when I think about this problem I just think of starting with coloring $1$ red then alternating until $1000$... There is obviously more to this problem, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: The problem asks you to find a coloring such that $a_1, a_2, \dots a_{17}$ never share a color, where $a_i = a_1 + (i-1)*d$. If you color even numbers blue and odd numbers red, then take $d=2$ to find a sequence of single color.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind the formula?

Comment: by an arithmetic progression of 17, do you mean one with 17 terms or with common difference of 17?

Comment: What I put above is all that I know for the question. I took it to be 17 consecutive terms. But I may not know what arithmetic progression means.

Comment: @VincentTjeng I added the whole question from my homework. After googling arithmetic progression I get that the difference between numbers of a sequence is 17. So 1, 18, 35,... But honestly I'm not sure what is meant by the question stated.

Comment: The formula is what is meant by arithmetic progression. The problem is definitely talking about a progression of 17 terms, with any difference. Even if you've never heard of the length of a sequence, a hint to this is just how trivial the other interpretation would be.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė So basically, in terms of differences what's the question saying? Because I'm thinking, now, of a sequence of length 17, obviously there are only so many differences. But what will I have to prove with these differences?

Comment: I would try the following coloring: let $n$ be red if the binary representation of $n$ has an even number of ones, blue otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been clarified in the comments, by an arithmetic progression of length $17$ they mean an arithmetic progression with $17$ terms, i.e. a progression of $17$ integers given by $a_i=a_1+(i-1)d$ for some integers $a_1$ and $d$, for instance $4,9,14,\dotsc,74,79,84$ for $a_1=4$ and $d=5$.

The claim can be proved using the [probabilistic method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method) by showing that the expected number of monochromatic arithmetic progressions of length $17$ upon independently colouring each integer with either colour with equal probability is less than $1$.